# AngularJS - Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': Partial keyframes are not supported

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am getting

> Error: Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': Partial keyframes are not supported.

while animating dom element inside ng-click method. I am passing the DOM ref in ng-click by using $event.

Here is the fiddle link - [fiddle containing issue](https://jsfiddle.net/rishi24/rd5rrczr/)

```
$event.currentTarget.animate({
    'height': '400px',
    'width': '400px'
  });
```

Though I can animate my DOM element by using jQuery - [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rishi24/rd5rrczr/1/)

```
$($event.currentTarget).animate({
    'height': '400px',
    'width': '400px'
  }, 1000);
```

I am not able to figure out why it is not working with simple angular code.

Comment: have you included `ng-animate` & `jQuery` as you are using `$`?

Comment: Yes, I have included jQuery(not using ng-animate) for getting the solution which I have mentioned in the second fiddle. But not in the first one.

Comment: use `angular.element($event.target)` and load `jQuery` before angular.

Comment: Thanks @PankajParkar, your solution worked. `jqLite does not support jQuery's animate function`. Thats why I need to load jQuery before angular.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Do you want me to add an answer

Comment: Yes please. Would be better if you can add more explation to it.

Comment: Check out my answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQLite` doesn't provide `animate` method out of the box, if you want it then you have to have load `jQuery`(before angular js, so that `angular.element` will also have jQuery methods) .

The other angular way solution would be you could load `ng-animate` module & have it register inside `myApp` module. You don't need to have `ng-click` handler over `element`

```
//below animation would apply on `container` class
myApp.animation('.container', [function() {
  return {
    click: function(element, doneFn) {
      angular.element(element).animate({
         'height': '400px',
         'width': '400px'
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it worked. I needed to load jQuery library before angular. Because `angular's jqLite does not support jQuery's animate funtion`.

[Angular's jqLite provides only the following jQuery methods](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

[Here is the working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rd5rrczr/2/)

```
angular.element($event.currentTarget).animate({
    'height': '400px',
    'width': '400px'
  });
```